# Clientside going serverside with node.js

Tags: node.js

I`ve been looking for a serverside language for some time, and python got my attention somewhat.
But as I already know and love javascript, I now want learn to code on the server with js and node.js.

Now, what books and what subjects do I need to learn to understand the serverside world better?

(let me know if Im to vague)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not aware of any printed resources about node.js. Some good places to start are:

- The official node.js [documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/)
- The web site [howtonode.org](http://howtonode.org/) with a lot of tutorials
- The [video](http://jsconf.eu/2009/video_nodejs_by_ryan_dahl.html) of Ryan Dahl's (node.js creator) talk at the JSConf.eu
- A nice [blog post](http://simonwillison.net/2009/Nov/23/node/) about node.js by Simon Willison
- The [mailing list archive](http://groups.google.com/group/nodejs)
- The source code of node.js projects on github

Comment: There is also the http://howtonode.org/ website with a lot of informative entries.

Answer (score 4):

The [HTTP/1.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html) is very informative.

Answer (score 1):

Learn python, it'll make you a better node.js programmer because it has good examples for all the networking features.

- [urllib](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html)
- [socket](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html)
- [file](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects)

JavaScript is my favorite language, but I've spent some time in python and the standard library is really good for learning the basics of sockets, file descriptors, and networking.